# How do I ask a question about ancient thing or people?

Tags: tense

> Do a slave get flogging when he be found cheating?

or

> Would a slave get flogging when he be found cheating?

Normally, slave is an ancient thing. But, there could be slave in the future.

So, I am confused about the tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some context for this.  Are you talking about the *booi aha* under the Qing dynasty, African Slaves in America or women forced into brothels in Europe? That will dictate your choice of tense:

> Did a *booi aha* slave get flogged when he was found cheating?
>   Are victims of sex trafficking flogged for cheating?

If you want to talk about all slaves up to now, the present perfect is possible:

> Have slaves ever been flogged for cheating?

It doesn't make much sense to ask this about the future. You can ask in a conditional sense, which isn't limited to past or future.

> If a slave cheated, would they be flogged?